# "Connection Refused" errors on Redis

Tags: php, linux, redis

I have a running Redis instance (v2.8) on our LAN, which is working and reachable via LAN IP and localhost. The problem is we're getting random "Connection refused" errors from the client side. They succeed many times, but failure happens often.

And there are no errors in Redis. It is not reporting any rejected connections, so i'm inclined to believe it's something in Linux. See the [INFO](http://redis.io/commands/info) output below:

```
info
# Server
redis_version:2.8.0
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:8c972dc122b48b0
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 3.2.0-56-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.6.3
process_id:32455
run_id:c2536f78b7277e44bb03d1872bb0ede6764bd719
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:531319
uptime_in_days:6
hz:10
lru_clock:204248
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Clients
connected_clients:11
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

# Memory
used_memory:20166048208
used_memory_human:18.78G
used_memory_rss:20565544960
used_memory_peak:20171368288
used_memory_peak_human:18.79G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.02
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.4.1

# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:548
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1386162582
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:142
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:1
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:104
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_current_size:10938614211
aof_base_size:5791948107
aof_pending_rewrite:0
aof_buffer_length:0
aof_rewrite_buffer_length:0
aof_pending_bio_fsync:0
aof_delayed_fsync:4616

# Stats
total_connections_received:1024359
total_commands_processed:500283574
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:88
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:1
sync_partial_ok:5
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:79
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:225004198
keyspace_misses:17265265
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:294076

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:1
slave0:ip=192.168.0.203,port=6379,state=online,offset=13777559286,lag=1
master_repl_offset:13777559286
repl_backlog_active:1
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:13776510711
repl_backlog_histlen:1048576

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:4233.39
used_cpu_user:5293.61
used_cpu_sys_children:5679.02
used_cpu_user_children:115598.34

# Keyspace
db0:keys=73514342,expires=10,avg_ttl=39196243
```

I'm only seeing about 50 concurrent connections with occasional bursts so I don't think i'm hitting any file descriptor limits. I've raised the soft limit to 90,000 descriptors. The sysctl fs.file-max setting is also very high.

```
sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 1622320
```

We're not saturating our 100Mb/s LAN line. So what is the problem? We're constantly getting tickets from users complaining about "Connection refused" errors.

Comment: Is redis log not showing any errors? What about Output buffers limits or Query buffer limits, is it possible you are reaching these? What type of connection does your client make ,synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: can you post also you redis.conf

Comment: @Nik - No the logs don't show any errors. How do i check if i'm reaching Output/Query buffer limits. All connections are synchronous.

Comment: @Adil Did you find a solution to this problem? Your problem sounds very similar to mine and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. For me, the problem was that my **redis instance was only listening on the ipv4 address**, but the **hostname** (`localhost` in my case) that my application connected to **resolved to an ipv4 and ipv6 address**. Anytime the application used the ipv4 address, it worked. However, when it used the ipv6 address, it gave `Connection refused` errors.

To solve this, either **configure redis to listen both on ipv4 and ipv6 addresses**, or configure the application to use the ipv4 address instead of the hostname.

Comment: This is a useful answer. I don't have the setup at hand anymore, so I can't verify if this was the original problem or not. Although I do remember NOT setting up ipv6, as  we had a limited set of servers.

Answer (score 0):

check your "bind" configuration .

Maybe is limited to localhost and you have to open to your network.
in you config file :

```
bind * 
# instead of bind 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I have bound it to localhost and the LAN IP. It is reachable via LAN, fairly often i see "Connection refused" errors in my application logs.